# UseContext Get Data from API Returns null

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get data from the user but it always returns null, the problem here that the return function runs first so the getUser is null how can i render the useEffect before it returns the provider ?

Here is my code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from '../axios'

export const UserContexts = React.createContext();

const UserContext =  ({children}) => {



const [getUser, setGetUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post("/check",{}, { withCredentials: true });
      setGetUser(data);
      console.log("i render second")
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, [])
  
  const { Provider } = UserContexts;
  return (
    <Provider value={getUser} >
      {console.log("i render first ")}
      {children}
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default UserContext
```

**and here is the output :**

[image]

the problem here that it renders **Provider** then the **useContext** that i am trying to get the data then it calls the useEffect to get the data then returns it , how can i call useEffect before all of this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this outside of the context, in the root of the same file:

`const userPromise = axios.post("/check",{}, { withCredentials: true })`

Then in useEffect do

```js
useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await userPromise;
      setGetUser(data);
      console.log("i render second")
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, [])
```

It will run the request at the start of the app but also would sync well with your context, correctly handling absent and loaded states

If you want to wait on it until the value is there, you could try

```
getUser ? <Provider value={getUser} >
      {console.log("i render first ")}
      {children}
</Provider> : null
```

Comment: it still returning the same output it renders provider then the useEffect and returning null

Comment: Do you want to wait on useContext() until `getUser` is defined? Not possible without some extra code, i.e. an additional component wrapper. It's easier to just check for null in the component. That's the standard way.

Comment: yea i want to wait for the getUser to get the data first then it render the Provider component

Comment: Updated the answer - could you try that?

Comment: wow you are genius this is an awesome way to wait for the data , thank you its working perfectly